# How can I use a collection within an Oracle SQL statement

Tags: oracle, collections, plsql

I want to write an Oracle function that collects some data in multiple steps into a collection variable and use that collection data within a SELECT query like in this very simplified example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TESTFUNC01 RETURN VARCHAR2 AS 
  -- INT_LIST is declared globally as "TYPE INT_LIST IS TABLE OF INTEGER"
  MyList INT_LIST := INT_LIST();
  MyName VARCHAR2(512);
BEGIN
  MyList.Extend(3);
  MyList(0) := 1;
  MyList(1) := 2;
  MyList(2) := 3;

  SELECT Name INTO MyName
  FROM Item WHERE ItemId NOT IN MyList;
  RETURN MyName;
END TESTFUNC01;
```

Unfortunately the part "NOT IN MyList" is no valid SQL. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `table` function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TESTFUNC01 RETURN VARCHAR2 AS 
  -- INT_LIST is declared globally as "TYPE INT_LIST IS TABLE OF INTEGER"
  MyList INT_LIST := INT_LIST();
  MyName VARCHAR2(512);
BEGIN
  MyList.Extend(3);
  MyList(1) := 1;
  MyList(2) := 2;
  MyList(3) := 3;

  SELECT Name INTO MyName
  FROM Item WHERE ItemId NOT IN (select * from table(MyList));
  RETURN MyName;
END TESTFUNC01;
```

Answer (score 7):

If your using oracle 10 you could use the collections extensions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TESTFUNC01 RETURN VARCHAR2 AS 
  -- INT_LIST is declared globally as "TYPE INT_LIST IS TABLE OF INTEGER"
  MyList INT_LIST := INT_LIST();
  MyName VARCHAR2(512);
BEGIN
  MyList.Extend(3);
  MyList(1) := 1;
  MyList(2) := 2;
  MyList(3) := 3;

  SELECT Name INTO MyName
  FROM Item WHERE ItemId MEMBER OF MyList;
  RETURN MyName;
END TESTFUNC01;
```

for more details see [this post](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=303)

Answer (score 6):

You can do it like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TESTFUNC01 RETURN VARCHAR2 AS 
  -- INT_LIST is declared globally as "TYPE INT_LIST IS TABLE OF INTEGER"
  MyList INT_LIST := INT_LIST();
  MyName VARCHAR2(512);
BEGIN
  MyList.Extend(3);
  MyList(1) := 1;
  MyList(2) := 2;
  MyList(3) := 3;

  SELECT Name INTO MyName
  FROM Item WHERE ItemId NOT IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(MyList));
  RETURN MyName;
END TESTFUNC01;
```

Note that I've also changed the list indices. The start with 1 (not 0).

Answer (score 4):

> -- INT_LIST is declared globally as "TYPE INT_LIST IS TABLE OF
>   INTEGER"

That looks like a PL/SQL declaration.  SELECT statements use the SQL engine.  This means you need to declare your TYPE in SQL.

```
CREATE TYPE INT_LIST AS TABLE OF NUMBER(38,0);
/
```

Then you can use it in a SELECT statement:

```
SELECT Name INTO MyName
FROM Item WHERE ItemId NOT IN (select * from table(MyList));
```

---

Of course, you need to make sure that your query returns only one row, or that your program handles the TOO_MANY_ROWS exception.