# ORACLE stored procedure accept date range as input parameter

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

Need to alter the following stored procedure to accept an array of dates. Currently this stored procedure only accepts one date as an input parameter.

```
procedure get_expected_del_sku_sum(
        p_str               in   number,
        p_to_date           in   date,
        p_cursor           out   sku_qty_sum_ref)  is

        v_cursor            sku_qty_sum_ref;
        v_from_date         date;
        v_request_key        varchar2(100);
        begin

            v_from_date := trunc(p_to_date - 30);
            v_request_key:= p_str || '_' || p_to_date || '_' || current_timestamp;

            if (getTempTableRecCnt(v_request_key) = 0) then
                build_sku_qty_temp(p_str,v_from_date, p_to_date, v_request_key);
           end if;

            open v_cursor for
                select dept_id,dept_name,prdc_code,prdc_desc,brand_id,brand_name,sku_style,str_no,sku_no,color_code,color_name,null,sum(sku_qty)
                    from shp_trk_temp_wrk
                    where trunc(est_receipt_date) = trunc(p_to_date)
                      and request_key = v_request_key
                    group by dept_id,dept_name,prdc_code,prdc_desc,brand_id,brand_name,sku_style,str_no,sku_no,color_code,color_name
                    order by dept_id,sku_no;

           p_cursor := v_cursor;

        end  get_expected_del_sku_sum;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use a collection within an Oracle SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569918/how-can-i-use-a-collection-within-an-oracle-sql-statement)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option. I want to return employees who where hired on dates I pass to the procedure as a collection.

Types first:

```
SQL> create or replace type t_rec is object (datum date);
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type t_tab is table of t_rec;
  2  /

Type created.
```

Function:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_dates in t_tab)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open rc for select ename, hiredate
  7                from emp
  8                where hiredate in (select * from table(par_dates));
  9    return rc;
 10  end;
 11  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select f_test(t_tab(t_rec(date '1980-12-17'), t_rec(date '1981-02-20'))) result from dual;

RESULT
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

ENAME      HIREDATE
---------- ----------
SMITH      12/17/1980
ALLEN      02/20/1981


SQL>
```